# NFS SetAttr for ModifiedDate

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, nfs

I've using [nekodrive library.](https://github.com/nekoni/nekodrive)
And i need to add functionality to change last modified date of file. Found method SetAttr. [NFSv3.cs](https://github.com/nekoni/nekodrive/blob/master/NFSLibrary/Protocols/V3/NFSv3.cs) And apply similar to SetFileSize function to set modified date:

```
        public void SetLastModifiedDate(string FileFullName, DateTime LastModified)
    {
        if (_ProtocolV3 == null)
        { throw new NFSConnectionException("NFS Client not connected!"); }

        if (_MountProtocolV3 == null)
        { throw new NFSMountConnectionException("NFS Device not connected!"); }

        NFSAttributes Attributes = GetItemAttributes(FileFullName);

        SetAttributeArguments dpArgSAttr = new SetAttributeArguments();

        NFSTimeValue lastModified = new NFSTimeValue();
        lastModified.Seconds = (int)(LastModified - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        
        dpArgSAttr.Handle = new NFSHandle(Attributes.Handle, V3.RPC.NFSv3Protocol.NFS_V3);
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes = new MakeAttributes();
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.LastAccessedTime = new NFSTimeValue();
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.ModifiedTime = lastModified;
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.SetModifiedTime = TimeHow.SET_TO_CLIENT_TIME;
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.Mode = Attributes.Mode;
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.UserID = -1;
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.GroupID = -1;
        dpArgSAttr.Attributes.SetSize = false;
        dpArgSAttr.GuardCreateTime = new NFSTimeValue();
        dpArgSAttr.GuardCheck = false;

        ResultObject<SetAttributeAccessOK, SetAttributeAccessFAIL> pAttrStat =
            _ProtocolV3.NFSPROC3_SETATTR(dpArgSAttr);

        if (pAttrStat == null || pAttrStat.Status != NFSStats.NFS_OK)
        {
            if (pAttrStat == null)
            { throw new NFSGeneralException("NFSPROC3_SETATTR: failure"); }

            ExceptionHelpers.ThrowException(pAttrStat.Status);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately i get an error: Update synchronization mismatch was detected during a SETATTR operation. Error Code is **NFSERR_NOT_SYNC = 10002**

Exports file:

> /home/nfs *(rw)

Can anyone advice on what could be wrong? may be just NFS configuration?